# Storing JSON response in List, or HashMap

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I've got some JSON response from retrofit that I'm not sure how to deal it, could you help me with it? I just want to store it somewhere, but I think List wouldn't be good for it, so maybe HashMap? The response looks like

```
{ 
    "object" : 
    { 
        "key1" : "value1", 
        "key2" : "value2"
    }
}
```

and so on.. Could you give me any hint how should I store that? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the structure of Json fixed and defined? If so, you can use Jackson to convert it into Java Objects.
Also, what do you want to store this result for? I mean what is the issue in storing it simply as a String if the main motive for you is to store it somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to parse the Json string to a structured format. You can use jackson to map it to a hashmap.

You can do it as following

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

  public void foo() {
       String jsonString = " { \"object\" : { \"key1\" : \"value1\", \"key2\" : \"value2\" } } ";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {

            // convert JSON string to Map
            Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can get jackson from following dependency if you are using maven

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can read more at Jackson's [Main Portal page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap is the best way of storing it because it gives you access to special methods (such as `containsKey`, `containsValue`, and `compute`) which you can use to interpret and manipulate the data.

To avoid having to write boilerplate code, I'd recommend using a library to handle the parsing for you, such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). It will also help if you ever have to write your own JSON responses.